# Simplify Exponents with Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $11^x = 3^y = 99^z$, then $\frac 1x + \frac 1y + \frac 1z  = ?$

I couldn't solve it.

please help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and explain where you got stuck?

Comment: Take log on both sides.

Comment: Let $c=11^x=3^y=99^z$. Then use $c$ represent $x,y,z$. Can we solve it?

Comment: I first tried substituting values for x,y,and, z, but it did not help. Then I tried like this: 11^x x 3^y = 99^2z; but couldn't come to a conclusion

Comment: @Ramana : See my answer. You can't "find" the unique solution, because it is --not-- unique.

Comment: I'm a 7th grader, so I don't understand logarithms. Please, any other way to solve this?

Comment: @Ramana : My point is that you can't solve it... if this is your professor's assignment, either you missed an equation or your professor gave you a wrong assignment. Wouldn't be the first time that either of them happened in front of my eyes :P

Comment: @Ramana : I gave it some thought... does your professor assume that $x,y$ and $z$ are integers? Otherwise the only integer solution to this is $x=y=z=0$. (Damn. This means $\frac 1x$ is not even defined... Ugh.)

Comment: I'm being home schooled. Any, way, thank you very much for spending your time on this problem

Answer (score 1):

The equation tells you that
$$
x \log 11 = y \log 3 = z \log 99.
$$
In other words,
$$
x = y \frac{\log(3)}{\log(11)} = z \frac{\log(99)}{\log(11)}.
$$
This means
$$
\frac 1x + \frac 1y + \frac 1z = \frac 1x \left( 1 + \frac{\log(11)}{\log(3)} + \frac{\log(11)}{\log(99)} \right). 
$$
The value of $x$ determines the value of $\frac 1x + \frac 1y + \frac 1z$, but unless we know $x$, we can't do much more. In fact, there are still infinitely many solutions at this point.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I'm a 7th grader, so I don't understand logarithms. Please, any other way to solve this?

Comment: just to clarify Patrick's point, you can raise all the given equations to any power, so if (x,y,z) is a solution, then so is (rx,ry,rz) for any real r (even r=0).

Comment: Can you please give an answer based on what ever you said?

Comment: @Ramana : I couldn't know you didn't know how to use logarithms. The idea is essentially that if $11^x = 3^y = 99^z$, then
$$
11^{2x} = (11^x)^2 = (3^y)^2 = 3^{2y}
$$
and similarly
$$
3^{2y} = (3^y)^2 = (99^z)^2 = 99^{2z},
$$
hence if $(x,y,z)$ is a solution, so is $(2x,2y,2z)$ because $11^{2x} = 3^{2y} = 99^{2z}$, and by the same reasoning also $(4x,4y,4z)$, so you can keep going and get infinitely many solutions (because there exists a non-zero solution, but if you don't know about logarithms I don't know how I could explain to you the existence of this solution).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to understand.

Comment: @Ramana : Feel free to comment more if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is $x=0, y=0, z=0$.

---

$11^x = 3^y = 99^z$ has infinitely many solutions. For example, if x=1, we will have
$11 = 3^y = 99^z  \implies 3^y = 11 \implies y=2.18265834$
Similarly we have $99z = 11 \implies z= 0.521835197$
So $x=1,y=2.18265834, z= 0.521835197$ is a solution.

---

So there are infinitely many solution to this equation. However, I encourage you to learn more about logarithms because they are really very simple(and because you will look like a math wizard in your class). After learning logarithms, you will be able to understand Patrick's answer very easily. Here are some good places to learn about logarithms:
[Khan Academy: Logarithms](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/logarithms-tutorial)
[Purple Math: Logarithms](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/logs.htm)
[Brilliant.org](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/properties-of-logarithms/)